# Multi OAuth Authentication in Vertx

Tags: java, oauth, vert.x, oauth-2.0

I have the following code:

```
    Class<OAuthHandler> _tempClass = (Class<OAuthHandler>) Class.forName(providerClass);
    Constructor<OAuthHandler> oAuthHandlerConstructor = _tempClass.getDeclaredConstructor(Vertx.class);
    OAuthHandler oAuthHandler = oAuthHandlerConstructor.newInstance(vertx);
    OAuth2Auth oAuth2Auth = oAuthHandler.getoAuth2Auth();
    /* AccessToken accessToken = */ oAuth2Auth.getToken(oAuthHandler.getTokenConfig(code), accessTokenResponse -> {
        if (accessTokenResponse.failed()) {
            System.out.println("Failed to obtain token");
        } else {
            AccessToken accessToken = accessTokenResponse.result();
            // Return the token? Somehow.
        }
    });
```

The `oAuthHandler` is a provider specific implementation providing some config etc based on the provider name, and simply wraps around the methods provided by the [vertx-auth-oauth2](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-auth-oauth2/java/) library.

I would like to use the access token after it returns, but not inside the `getToken` Lambda, so I can get any information about the user I need.

Ive seen some things about Vert.x Futures, but unsure if I can even use them here, any suggestions or examples to solutions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Vert.x OAuth2 support is not vendor specific. According to the documentation http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_oauth2authhandler_handler you will see that the same code can handle the following providers:

- Google
- Twitter
- Github
- LinkedIn
- Facebook
- Keycloak

and as soon as 3.4 is released some small fixes will make it also compatible with:

- Azure AD

Also the handler is generic so if you have your own provider you can also use it.

Now regarding the second part of the question how to use the the token directly, then you probably do not want the `OAuth2Handler` since it hides all this from you and you want to interact with `OAuth2` client directly:

http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-auth-oauth2/java/#_getting_started

From the documentation above there is an getting started code example that allows you to interact with the get token without using reflection. This is way better since you will not be hurt if internal api's change.

Comment: I would not say it is good document. unfortunately. some parts here and there. that's probably it is not accepted answer.. and also: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vertx/5cPvaXbfCbU/uGCEo70jAQAJ